# Invalid default value for 'dateAdded'

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a stupid problem with SQL that I can't fix.

```
ALTER TABLE  `news` 
 ADD  `dateAdded` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `dateAdded` )
```

Error:

```
(#1067)Invalid default value for 'dateAdded'
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but why do you `AUTO_INCREMENT` `DATETIME` ?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is only acceptable on `TIMESTAMP` fields. `DATETIME` fields must be left either with a null default value, or no default value at all - default values must be a constant value, not the result of an expression.

relevant docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html

You can work around this by setting a post-insert trigger on the table to fill in a "now" value on any new records.

Comment: It looks like as of mysql 5.6.5, you can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with DATETIME fields.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: Thanks Frank, found this problem when trying to import an exported db from the latest xampp to an earlier one.

Comment: The HCD , Frank ... found same issue exporting from MariaDb 10.x to MariaDB 5.5 ... thanks

Comment: This error happens in mariadb 5.5 also.  Upgrade to mariadb  10 and its solved. Thanks Frank

Comment: MySQL query browser seems to have a bug setting the default value for TIMESTAMPS. Use this query instead `ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN timestamp_colname TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Answer (score 54):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is version specific and is now allowed for `DATETIME` columns as of version 5.6.

See [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: are you sure ? I get the above error in version 5.7.x

Comment: MySQL query browser seems to have a bug setting the default value for TIMESTAMPS. Use this query instead `ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN timestamp_colname TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;`

Answer (score 22):

Also do note when specifying `DATETIME` as `DATETIME(3)` or like on MySQL 5.7.x, you also have to add the same value for `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)`. If not it will keep throwing '*Invalid default value*'.

Comment: This solved the problem for me on 5.7.x. My datetime fields were defined as datetime(6) and using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) solved the problem

Comment: This is highly worthy noting.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, 
following fix solved my problem.

- Select Type as 'TIMESTAMP'
- *DON'T ENTER ANYTHING IN LENGTH/VALUES FIELD. KEEP IT BLANK*
- Select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as Default value.

I am using MySQL ver 5.5.56

Answer (score 0):

I have mysql version 5.6.27 on my LEMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value works fine.

Answer (score 0):

mysql version 5.5 set datetime default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP will be report error
you can update to version 5.6 , it set datetime default value as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

Change the type from datetime to timestamp and it will work! 
I had the same issue for mysql 5.5.56-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
Hope it can help... sorry if depricated

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by changing `DATE` to `DATETIME`