# MySQL: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for date field works locally but not on server

Tags: mysql, database, import, export

I have a date column whose default value is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. It works fine locally, but when I did an export and tried to create the database on my hosting I get this:

```
`Invalid default value for 'created'`
```

...from this code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `cloned` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount_due` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `vat` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `discount` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_paid` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` mediumtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded) says that, apparently, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is an acceptable default only for datetime, not date, columns. But like I say, it works locally, just not remotely.

Could it be to do with the difference in MySQL versions?

- Local MySQL: protocol v10 / server v5.6.16
- Remote MySQL: protocol v10 / server v5.5.35

Am I getting away with this locally because of the higher server version?

Comment: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP is an acceptable default only for datetime, not date, columns" - In your SQL `created` is a datetime column...

Comment: May be this is the reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489548/why-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current-timestamp-in-default-cla

Comment: @ODaniel - well spotted, so that matter would appear to be n/a to me. Senk - thanks, I just had a read of that. Seems like it could be a version thing, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work for MySQL 5.5; before mysql 5.6.5 `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` works only for `TIMESTAMP`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

It's working for you locally, because you are using MySQL 5.6.16 there.

Comment: Thanks - as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

In the MySQL manual a Timestamp datatype is recommended for use with "DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Also consider this (taken from the MySQL manual): 
One TIMESTAMP column in a table can have the current timestamp as the default value for initializing the column, as the auto-update value, or both. It is not possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one column and the auto-update value for another column.

Comment: Does the auto-update also work on two columns locally?

Answer (score 1):

try using

`created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,