# What is the reason why MySQL is telling me "Invalid default value for 'postdate'"?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 Windows servers running MySQL, one of them running version 5.1 and the other running version 5.7. I am trying trying to copy a database from the MySQL 5.7 over to the 5.1 on the other server and believe it's the difference in versions (new syntax in 5.7?) that is causing this error, but I could be wrong.

After Exporting through phpMyAdmin the database I in the 5.7 version and trying to Import in the 5.1 version I'm getting the error

> MySQL said: Documentation   #1067 - Invalid default value for
>   'postdate'

on the command

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jobs` (

 `id` mediumint( 9 ) NOT NULL ,
 `title` varchar( 200 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `descr` varchar( 5000 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `postdate` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT =5 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
```

Any idea why?

Comment: @Mihai Hmmm that's what the program `mysqldump` generated, though. Does `mysqldump` make errors sometimes?

Comment: 5.1 cant have default on datetime column,change it to timestamp\

Comment: you can check this question [invalid-default-value-for-dateadded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 5.1, the default value has to be a constant value (e.g. `NULL` is acceptable) except for the `timestamp` type where `current_timestamp` is allowed. I.e., for a date or datetime you cannot use `current_date`,  `now` or `current_timestamp`.

So you either stick to the `datetime` type for your `postdate` column and you have to give up `current_timestamp` as a default value (you can maybe set up a trigger for the purpose, see examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168736/how-do-you-set-a-default-value-for-a-mysql-datetime-column)), or - depending on your requirements - consider using `timestamp` (which has a different range of values).

The corresponding section of the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/data-type-defaults.html) says:

> With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be
>   a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot
>   set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such
>   as NOW() or CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that you can specify
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default for a TIMESTAMP column.