# current_timeStamp is not working

Tags: mysql

I tried this code

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    userId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NUll,
    account VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(200) NOT Null,
    isActive varchar(10) NOT NUll,
    
    createdDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NUll,
    updatedDate DATETIME 
);
```

but the following error will come

## 1067 - Invalid default value for 'createdDate'

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid default value for 'dateAdded'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded)

Comment: which mysql version you are using ? before 5.6 it was only allowed for `timestamp` data type.

Comment: Use: `createdDate ` datetime DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Answer (score 4):

Use simply `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
    userId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NUll, 
    account VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, password varchar(200) NOT Null, 
    isActive varchar(10) NOT NUll,
    createdDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NUll,
   updatedDate DATETIME 
);
```

> In addition, you can initialize or update any TIMESTAMP column to the
>   current date and time by assigning it a NULL value, unless it has been
>   defined with the NULL attribute to permit NULL values.

For more knowledge click the link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype `datetime` to `timestamp` it will work.

```
CREATE TABLE users ( userId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NUll, 
account VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL, 
password varchar(200) NOT Null, 
isActive varchar(10) NOT NUll,
createdDate **timestamp** DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() NOT NUll,
updatedDate DATETIME )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it should work.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
userId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NUll,
account VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
password varchar(200) NOT Null,
isActive varchar(10) NOT NUll,
createdDate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NUll,
updatedDate DATETIME 
);
```