# invalid default value for variable last_updated in the below code

Tags: mysql

why do i get invalid default value error for the variable "last_updated"?
note i am getting this error while i run the following code in MySQL console in phpmyadmin

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
   `article_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `content_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `article_body` text NOT NULL,
    `last_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
     PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=532 ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid default value for 'dateAdded'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `last_updated` column's data type to `timestamp` rather than `datetime`.  This will allow the use of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value.

As it happens, these two data types are represented in the same format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. So if/when you use the data, you shouldn't run into any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL server version, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is allowed since version 5.6.5 as `DEFAULT` for `DATETIME` type, otherwise you should use either `TIMESTAMP` type or maintain it outside.