# Error in setting the default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, default-value, alter-table

I am having problem while altering a table. I need a column with data type DATETIME to take default value as current date/time and on update also it should automatically update it's value to current date/time. I am writing the following SQL

```
ALTER TABLE `groups` 
CHANGE COLUMN `modified` `modified` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I am getting the following error message.

```
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'modified'
```

The MySQL version I'm using is 5.5.49 on a Ubuntu 14.04.1 system.

Please let me know how this can be fixed.

Comment: MySQL does not support dynamic default values (save for a tiny exception in `TIMESTAMP` columns).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to MySQL 5.6.5, you can only use the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` default value for columns of type `TIMESTAMP`.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9005872/1293303

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this is because you already have another column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as default.

In MySQL versions prior to 5.6 this is a problem:

[Why there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489548/why-there-can-be-only-one-timestamp-column-with-current-timestamp-in-default-cla)