# I am getting a MySQL insert error in database - "Invalid default value"

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

When I execute

```
ALTER TABLE foodapp_order
ADD COLUMN customer_ar VARCHAR(15) AFTER customer_name;
```

Then I am getting this error:

> Error
>
> SQL query:
>
> ALTER TABLE foodapp_order ADD COLUMN customer_ar VARCHAR(15) AFTER
> customer_name
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
> f#1067 - Invalid default value for 'order_date'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid default value for 'dateAdded'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005766/invalid-default-value-for-dateadded)

Comment: the error seems to refer to a column which is not mentioned in your query. So I guess the issue is with something existing in your table, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Local Databases/zb_server/foodapp_order/  http://localhost/phpmyadmin/tbl_sql.php?db=zb_server&table=foodapp_order&token=9792f4eda35aa1d9cce5f79fdabbefc4

    


 Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available. 

Your SQL query has been executed successfully.

show variables like 'sql_mode'



sql_mode STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,E...

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the error message, it seems to be an issue with the current schema of the table and the column `order_date`.
Check for any type mismatch with `order_date` default value, from the schema.

Answer (score 0):

A problem is there with something else. You may have the *order_date* column with some default value.

The format of default value may be something like

```
order_date default '0000-00-00'
```

Make sure you have corrected the "NO_ZERO_DATE" strict setting.

> In strict mode, don't allow '0000-00-00' as a valid date. Hence failing.

Refer [NO_ZERO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date)

Answer (score 0):

When I am using

```
set global sql_mode="NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES,STRICT_TRANS_TABLE,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

this setting is working fine.